# Change indexes of an array by comparing it with the other array keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

i have an array like this,

```js
data = [
  {
    DOCDT: "2020-06-06T18:59:48.000Z",
    DOCNO: "001",
    IREF1: "50",
    IREF2: "100",
    NETAMOUNT: 30000,
  },
  {
    DOCDT: "2020-06-06T18:59:48.000Z",
    DOCNO: 2,
    IREF1: 40,
    IREF2: 90,
    NETAMOUNT: 40000,
  },
];
```

i want to compare its keys to another array which is this

```js
jsonData = [
  "DOCNO",
  "DOCDT",
  "IREF1",
  "IREF2",
  "NETAMOUNT"
]
```

i want to change the order of **data** array based on **jsonData**, is there any way in es6 or javascript to do that.
i tried using this but it doesnt work

```
this.data.sort(function(a, b){  
  return jsonData.indexOf(a) - jsonData.indexOf(b);
});
```

Comment: Do you want to sort by `docno`, then `docdt` etc? Can you add an expected output?

Comment: in your sort function, `a` and `b` are objects. `jsonData.indexOf(a)` will not work. change it to `jsonData.indexOf(a["DOCNO])`

Comment: the thing is data is coming from api so it can be in any order. my Expected output is data should be arranged as the order of jsonData array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `sortObject` method and use it over map. I shuffled data keys order to make the output is expected. Hope this helps.

```js
data = [
  {
    IREF1: "50",
    IREF2: "100",
    NETAMOUNT: 30000,
    DOCDT: "2020-06-06T18:59:48.000Z",
    DOCNO: "001",
  },
  {
    DOCNO: 2,
    IREF1: 40,
    DOCDT: "2020-06-06T18:59:48.000Z",
    IREF2: 90,
    NETAMOUNT: 40000,
  },
];

jsonData = ["DOCNO", "DOCDT", "IREF1", "IREF2", "NETAMOUNT"];

// When Object.fromEntries not available in your environment
const objFromEntries = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ((acc[key] = val), acc), {});

const sortObject = (obj) =>
  objFromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).sort(
      ([a], [b]) => jsonData.indexOf(a) - jsonData.indexOf(b)
    )
  );

const updated = data.map(sortObject);

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it's giving me an error, Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Comment: @sp16bs0002, `Object.fromEntries` method (recent JS method) not available in the JS version you are using. Updated my answer to have alternate method for this.